# bundles in requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am new to requireJS and tring to learn it so that i can use it in my current application.

While reading API documentation of requireJS, I came across **bundles** (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) as configuration option of requireJS

```
requirejs.config({
    bundles: {
        'primary': ['main', 'util', 'text', 'text!template.html'],
        'secondary': ['text!secondary.html']
    }
});

require(['util', 'text'], function(util, text) {
    //The script for module ID 'primary' was loaded,
    //and that script included the define()'d
    //modules for 'util' and 'text'
});
```

API Explanation :

*Bundles config is useful if doing a build and that build target was not an existing module ID, or if you have loader plugin resources in built JS files that should not be loaded by the loader plugin.*

But here I am not able to understand that why we need bundle and when we should use use it?

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js You can also combine all scripts into one without the dependency to Modulerr.js

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When building a large SPA (Single Page App), it is imperative that you concatenate and minify your files. The problem with doing it, is that you might end up with one massive minified js file that can get as large as a few megs.

In order to solve this, require introduces the bundle feature, which allows you to pack your files in several bundles, and those would be loaded only when needed.

So, for example if you have a page with 'home' and 'about', you can create a bundle like:

```
bundles: {
        'home': ['home', 'util', 'text', 'text!home.html'],
        'about': ['text!about.html']
    }
```

and then the about page resources would only be served when you actually click the about page. That way you get lazy loading of resources.

For better explanation and example, watch this great video: http://vimeo.com/97519516

The relevant part is around the 39 min.

Comment: Can you bundle all modules inside a folder, without listing all of them explicitly? Btw great video indeed.

Comment: I believe what you have given here is from the require js file. Can you also point out how to use this actually in the main config?

Comment: I came up with a similar question below, hope you guys see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679457/requirejs-config-bundles-option-and-r-js