# Exclude shim from require js optimized build

Tags: requirejs, durandal, requirejs-optimizer

I've a durandal WebApp which uses require js to load modules.
There's a shim configured for tinymce. It works OK when using the non-optimized version.
When I use r.js to optimize the code, I want to exclude tinymce from the bundle, but it's always included. 
Does anyone know how to exclude the shims from being included in the optimized build?
I'm using gulp-durandal, and I've successfully excluded other modules, using the excludeShadow setting, but it doesn't seam to work for shims, or I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT:
I managed to fix the problem by manually setting in the gulp-durandal file the exclude array in rjsConfigAdapter. For some reason the moduleFilter function didn't excluded the files, but the exclude array did the job

Comment: Why do you want to exclude anything from the bundle?

Comment: Because it's not a functionality that is used very often. I prefer to load it on demand, than to increase the initial load time.

Comment: Why don't you try to create a separate requirejs bundle then? [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175914/bundles-in-requirejs)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `paths.tinymce=empty:` in your r.js command line call.

Or this (in your require config), if you use it via Grunt.js or something:

```
paths: {
    tinymce: "empty:"
}
```