# How to bundle an backbone application

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, marionette, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

We have a backbone application with require.js for loading js, while loading this application on chrome it takes around 30 seconds to load the page completely.

On inspecting the network tab I found that the stalled time is actually the one which is causing issue, we know that stall time is default functionality of chrome where it loads only 6 requests at a time.
[image]
As we can see in this image the load time is 17.22 ms but the stall time is 63.96 ms
It is observed that the .hbs files takes longer stall time than .js

Is there any way that we can bundle our backbone application so that the no of requests that the browser makes reduces

Comment: what was the result in other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are supposed to use RequireJS with BackboneJS, you have this answer : [bundles in requireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175914/bundles-in-requirejs/25592166)